# Using Web AppBuilder Developer Edition with HTTP/HTTPS?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal, http

I am using;

- ArcGIS for Server Standard Enterprise 10.4.1
- Portal for ArcGIS 10.4.1

Also i am using Web AppBuilder Developer Edition 2.3 and deploying webapps in our server.

Normally when i deploy a webapp to server root directory and reach site a http web adress my app waits at startup loading screen then redirect to https format and starts.

When i create an app and deploy to my server with WAB 2.7 version, with http web adress my app do not start and stuck at startup screen with this error;

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.js?wab_dv=2.7:199 jimu.js init...
init.js:379 Uncaught Error: Invalid template: <div>
  <div class="loading-container">
      <div data-dojo-attach-point="imgDiv" class="img-div">
      </div>
      <p data-dojo-attach-point="textNode"></p>
  </div>
</div><script id="ftnt_topbar_script" src="//mydomain:8011/bar7cbf8c34e03e2da1a4f946e2ce708e5c.js" type="text/javascript" class="0" ></script>
    at Function.e.getCachedTemplate (init.js:379)
    at Object.buildRendering (init.js:378)
    at Object.create (init.js:355)
    at Object.postscript (init.js:354)
    at new <anonymous> (init.js:200)
    at Object.loadConfig (ConfigManager.js?wab_dv=2.7:130)
    at Object.initApp (main.js?wab_dv=2.7:229)
    at init.js:211
    at ja (init.js:28)
    at init.js:29
e.getCachedTemplate @ init.js:379
buildRendering @ init.js:378
create @ init.js:355
postscript @ init.js:354
(anonymous) @ init.js:200
loadConfig @ ConfigManager.js?wab_dv=2.7:130
initApp @ main.js?wab_dv=2.7:229
(anonymous) @ init.js:211
ja @ init.js:28
(anonymous) @ init.js:29
ka @ init.js:28
ha @ init.js:28
g @ init.js:31
(anonymous) @ init.js:35
bar7cbf8c34e03e2da1a4f946e2ce708e5c.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

But when i add **https** in front of adress web aplication starts with no problem.

what changed in 2.7 version that i get this error?